# How to create an elbow connector from scratch programatically?

Tags: path, shapes

An "elbow connector" in MS-Word is a 3-segment line with a control point in the middle as shown

[image]

where if I move the yellow control point sideways, then the length of the two lines on either side change accordingly while the end points remain the same.

I am trying to understand how this works so that I can re-create this. Is there a "line equation" for such a line? How would I go about re-creating this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to GDSE; well in here we only discuss about visual things but if you want to code it then you must post your question in https://stackoverflow.com/ :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a programming question perhaps better suited for stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a programmer, but that curve is = three line segments; one vertical between two horizontal. There's 5 placement numbers. Four of them are endpoint coordinates, say X1,Y1,X2,Y2 and the one, say S is the placement of the vertical piece as percents of the horizontal distance of the endpoints. S is between 0 and 1.

If you already can draw a line between points (A,B) and (C,D), then you draw three lines

left part starting from (X1,Y1), ending at (S(X2-X1)+X1, Y1)

mid part starting from (S(X2-X1)+X1, Y1), ending at (S(X2-X1)+X1, Y2)

right part starting from (S(X2-X1)+X1,Y2), ending at (X2,Y2)

S(X2-X1)+X1 is, of course, calculated only once.